# Service Delay In created service Error 1053

Tags: windows-service

Heya all bit of a noob when it comes to all this but I created my own service to start an EXE as a service but it keeps telling me it didnt respond in a timely fashion is there any way to give it abit more time to start up.

Comment: More detail needed! How did you do this? Are you using `SRVANY.EXE` or have you written your own service in .NET or similar to start an EXE?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to give it more time to start up, but it probably won't help - if it's timing out when starting, giving it more time usually doesn't fix the problem, actually.